# Update enum to the next or previous state

Tags: c#, enums

I have an enum type and added two helper functions to set the enum to the next value or previous value but it doesn't seem to update and i do not know why.

My enums are setup like this:

```
public enum State
{
    None = 0,
    A = 1,
    B = 2,
    Complete = 3
}
```

My helper methods look like this:

```
public static State Next(this State state) => (State)Math.Clamp((int)state++, (int)State.None, (int)State.Complete);
public static State Prev(this State state) => (State)Math.Clamp((int)state--, (int)State.None, (int)State.Complete);
```

And i use the functions like this:

```
print(_state);
_state = _state.Next();
print(_state);
```

However the prints give me the same result both times:

```
A
A
```

What am i getting wrong here?

Comment: Do you want `Next` to always return the max value once it gets to `Complete`? Or should it roll over and return the min value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your helper methods should be written as follows:

```
public static State Next(this State state) => (State)Math.Clamp((int)state + 1, (int)State.None, (int)State.Complete);
public static State Prev(this State state) => (State)Math.Clamp((int)state - 1, (int)State.None, (int)State.Complete);
```

Your problem was that you were using the [postfix operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/arithmetic-operators#postfix-increment-operator) `(int)state++` and `(int)state--`:

> The result of x++ is the value of x *before* the operation.

Thus you were passing the original values of `state` into `Math.Clamp()`, which it duly returned.

Demo [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/GbHToD).